# rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check(..) and required arguments

Tags: roslaunch, catkin, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Context: package with launchfile A, which includes launchfile B (from another package) and passes one required argument to B. This argument has no default value.

After adding a call to `rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check(..)` to the `CMakeLists.txt`, `make test` fails with:

```
FAILURE:
[launch/A.launch]:
    arg 'my_arg' is not defined. 

Arg xml is <arg name="my_arg_for_B" value="$(arg my_arg)"/>
```

It seems the test fails because the required argument (`my_arg`) isn't set when `make test` is called, so `my_arg` can't be passed on to included launchfile B.

Does anyone know of any way to provide values for required arguments when testing launchfiles?

---

I've found one approach / work around: set an environment variable using `rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check(FILE var=val)`, check for this in launchfile A, and provide a default for `my_arg` if the environment variable is set. Example:

```
<arg name="my_arg" unless="$(optenv ROSBUILD_ROSLAUNCH_TESTING false)" />
<arg name="my_arg" if="$(optenv ROSBUILD_ROSLAUNCH_TESTING false)" default="" />
```

While this works (tests succeed, and in normal usage with `roslaunch` `my_arg` stays a required argument), I don't like it very much as I'd have to replicate this construct for every argument, in all my launchfiles. If possible, I'd like to avoid this.

---

This is somewhat related to '[rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check fails for included files using launch file arguments](http://answers.ros.org/question/38241/rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check-fails-for-included-files-using-launch-file-arguments/)', but the OP in that question uses substitution arguments in the defaults for arguments.

---

Edit: I thought this was related to [ros_comm/pull/276: Fix arg parsing when computing dependencies in roslaunch-check](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/276), but I get the same errors from `rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check(..)` after applying that patch (and using the resulting pkg in a chained workspace).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75844/rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check(..)-and-required-arguments/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2013-08-31

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-04**:
The simple solution is to provide a default parameter value. I presume you are not willing to do it that way.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2013-09-04**:
@joq: yes, that is another work around. Although I have quite some args that do not have sensible defaults and some are even dangerous if not given a proper value. I like the fact my users get error messages about required arguments, as it means they are not using the launchfiles correctly.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-05**:
I understand. Just checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would seem this is impossible at this time.

For the packages involved, I've resorted to removing the `rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check(..)` from the `CMakeLists.txt` for now.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I have a work around for launch check not supporting parameters.  I’ve been going through the moveit and motoman launch files and realized that the more complicated launch files are really more like code in that they dynamically can changed based on the parameters that are passed in.  Given that, I wondered if we should treat the launch check more like we treat unit tests.  This is what I came up with: https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/blob/hydro/motoman_sia10d_support/test/launch_test.xml

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2014-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-02-03**:
This is a nice way to work around this limitation. +1. See http://answers.ros.org/question/125676/roslaunch_add_file_check-and-build-dependencies/ for some additional discussion regarding this.